# Export a decision tree for each k fold when doing cross validation with scikit-learn package

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

Upon performing cross-validation on an instance of *RandomForestRegressor()* with the helper function *cross_val_score()*, which in its turn receives as parameter that instance, do you know if it would be possible to generate a single decision tree (one of the random forest estimators), and consequently export it to an image, per each of the k folds, where for each of those, it is built a random forest (I guess)?

On the other hand, when calling *fit()* helper function on that instance of *RandomForestRegressor()* I'm able to get a specific decision tree/estimators calling the attribute *estimators_[nr_of_tree_in_range_1_to_nr_of_estimators]* for that same random forest regresssor instance, and then exporting it to a .dot file and so on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe there's a quicker way but usually when you want to do something somewhat unconventional with `cross_val_score`, the solution requres that you write your own cross validation function.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought at first glance! Thanks @Stev